# why can super access non static variable of superclass?

Tags: java, static, super

```
class B {
   int xB = 10;
}

class C extends B {
   int xB = 4;

   C() {
      System.out.println(super.xB);
      System.out.println(B.xB);
   }
}
```

i get an error for B.xB . It says xB is not static therefore you cant use it. But it doesnt give me an error for super.xB. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you define `xB` in the subclass it basically hides the `xB` variable of superclass. So if you print `this.xB` you will get 4. Using `super` is the way to access hidden variable of superclass and it has nothing to do with static variables. Also as you correctly guessed since `xB` is instance variable (non static) in super class you cannot access it just with class name.

You can try

```
class C extends B {
    int xB = 4;

    C() {
        System.out.println(this.xB);
        System.out.println(super.xB);
        System.out.println(((B)this).xB); //same behavior as super.xB
        //System.out.println(B.xB); // Not allowed as xB is not static in B
    }
}
```

you will get

```
4
10
10
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you're accessing the variable xB from B class via class identifier, not via this or super. Either `super` is fine or you can do `((B)this).xB`.

Answer (score 1):

`super` is used to access variables and functions of superclass.`super` is used to call the super class constructor.

Static variables are variables whose values are common to all the objects of a class.
It's like one copy for all the objects.
Example:

```
int a;   //variable of someclass
static int b; //variable of someclass
someclass ob=new someclass();
someclass ab=new someclass();
```

`ab` and `ob` will have different copies of  variable `a` since `a` is not static.
But they will share one copy of `b` .

therefore, `a` is accessed using object name(since each obbject has a unique copy).

```
ob.a=1;
ob.b=2;
```

And `b` is accessed using class name.
`someclass.b=4`(value remains 4 for all the object).

Thus,static variable means just one copy and therefore,it's shared by all objects and is not unique to an object and that's the reason it cannot be accessed using object name.

It's the same with the variable `xb`.It's not a static variable and so every object has a copy.So access it using object name.